# Non maven jar dependencies giving error in pom.xml maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to install some non maven jars in my maven project.

Step 1: I am using `maven-antrun-plugin` to generate jar of the non maven projects using ant(since the non-maven projects are Ant-based) in pre-package phase.

Step 2: Then I use `maven-install-plugin` to install the plugin to the local repository in package phase

Step 3: I also use `maven-war-plugin` to package all of them in a war in install phase

Also I have all the non maven projects added as dependencies in pom.xml
When I run mvn-install on my project, pom gives an error: `Missing artifact for non maven jars`.
`The POM for com.non_maven:com.non_maven:jar:version is missing, no dependency information available`

If the package phase is run then only the non maven jars will be installed in the repository. But it seems Maven expects all the dependencies already present in the repository.
I can solve this issue by separately installing the non maven jars in the 
maven repository and then running pom.xml to create the war.
But I want to do these steps using the single pom.
How can I achieve this ?
Thanks

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.swte.sca</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.1.19</version>
    <name>MyProject</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>common-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>com.non_maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>com.non_maven</artifactId>
                            <version>${version}</version>
                            <file>F:/addressMaven</file>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                      <executions>
                        <execution>
                          <id>copy-war-file</id>
                          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                          <configuration>
                                <target name="display">
                                  <ant antfile="src/main/ant/build.xml"/>
                                </target>
                          </configuration>
                          <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                          </goals>
                        </execution>
                      </executions>
                </plugin>   
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>F:\Folder\APP</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>F:/addressMaven</directory>
     </resource>
</resources>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.swte.ojdbc7</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.swte.ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
  </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.non_maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.non_maven</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
  </dependency>




    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi, I guess the pom can be useful, but if I understand it well, then its simple example you have to build all non-maven dependencies before you run the build of dependent app / module

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get your point "the pom can be useful" Please explain

Comment: If you will attach how your pom.xml looks now, I guess it can be useful for others for investigation

Comment: I have updated pom file in my question

Answer (score 2):

From your pom, I can see that you are not using module.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

I have seen similar problems solved by modules.

You can keep your master pom for your build as it is, and you extract your specific build step in a dedicated module, with a child pom.

```
<version>1.1.19</version>
<name>MyProject</name>
<modules>
    <module>child-module</module>
</modules>
<build>
```

In the folder /child-module, you create a pom similar to your parent's one:

```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.swte.sca</groupId>
      <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.19</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.swte.sca</groupId>
   <artifactId>non-maven-module</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
```

And you can write there your build step for your module

Comment: Pom file was attached :) Btw that should be the comment, instead the answer

Comment: I agree, but you cannot comment with less than 50 reputation :)

Comment: ah, ok then all fine- then you can edit the post to provide some tangible example :)

Comment: @Luc how to keep two pom.xml in the same project ? I don't have any child projects. I can keep them with a different name but then how will I specify it in the module tag in parent pom ?

Comment: Further in parent pom.xml, where I mention the non maven jar dependency still shows the error.

Comment: I just updated my answer, with a bit of info to create module. I hope this will help.